# How to match a text in a string, that does not contain a specific word and does not contain a word with letters and digits?

Tags: regex

Example 1:

`abc defg hi123`

In that string I need to match `defg`.

Example 2:

`abc defg hijkl mn123`

In that string I need to match `defg hijkl`.

I have the first pattern, that matches a text not containing "abc":

`\w+\b(?<!\babc)`

And I have the second pattern, that matches a word with letters and digits:

`(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*`

But I think I need to invert the second pattern to match a text that does not contain a word with letters and digits - I tried, but unsuccessfully.
Then, I guess, I need to combine these 2 patterns in one with "|" (or without it):

`pattern 1|pattern 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will match your values using a word boundary and a negative lookahead:

```
\b(?!\w*abc)[^\W\d]+\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?!\w*abc)` Assert what is on the right does not contain `abc`
- `[^\W\d]+` Negated character class, match 1+ times a word character except a digit
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a7OGh6/1)

Comment: Thanx, I forgot about it. And how to mark also the parts with digits only? https://regex101.com/r/y1yoeZ/1

Comment: Can you give an example?